# BlueNRG-MS only allow known device to connect

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluenrg

I have a BLE peripheral with the STM BlueNRG-MS chip. I use the bluenrg API.
The peripheral should be generally discoverable, but only known devices should be allowed to connect.

I thought I can achieve this by checking the `bdaddr` of the central device in the `EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE` callback and depending on whether the address is known or not, I'll allow the connection. In addition I would have a pairing mode where I accept all incomming connection requests and would add new central devices to the list of known devices.

```
  case EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE:
    {
      evt_le_connection_complete *cc = (void *)evt->data;
      /*TODO: check if peer address is listed or if HMI accepts new pairing
       * If in pairing mode, add device to the list and accept connection, otherwise
       * go through list and if not found, refuse connection.*/
      if(acceptNewPairing){
          LOG("CR from %d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d", cc->peer_bdaddr[0], cc->peer_bdaddr[1], cc->peer_bdaddr[2], cc->peer_bdaddr[3], cc->peer_bdaddr[4], cc->peer_bdaddr[5]);
          GAP_ConnectionComplete_CB(cc->peer_bdaddr, cc->handle);         
      }
  }
  break;
```

My problem is that the `bdaddr` is not constant but changes after a certain time, so I don't regonize the central device. How can I overcome this problem? What is the proper way to implement this feature that most known bluetooth devices offer?

**Update:**
It seems that the behavior can be achieved using the function

```
hci_le_add_device_to_white_list(uint8_t bdaddr_type, tBDAddr bdaddr);
```

After that, the device is discoverable even if I set the discoverability to `WHITE_LIST_FOR_ALL`. My problem now is that the whitelist doesn't seem to be persistent, if I do a reboot of the device I have to go to pairing mode again in order to see it. Does someone know how I can save the whitelist?

What does `aci_gap_configure_whitelist()` do? Because if I call this function, it seems like my whitelist gets wipped out.

**Update2:**

In the STM Document PM0257 (sec. 3.10.1) I found a reference to what looks like to be the procedure I'm looking for. So I consider this a step forward. The problem is that the referenced function `aci_gap_add_device_to_resolving_list` doesn't exist in my bluenrg API. Any idea what I should use instead?

Comment: The address you receive is most likely a Random Private Address. This is a BLE security feature to prevent tracking of devices for a longer time. If the address is 'resolvable' you can pair and bond the devices to exchange a Identity Resolving Key (IRK) which can be used to resolve the random address and identify the device. Read [this](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-address-privacy-ble/) for more informations

Comment: That's what I thought... and this has to be done manually on only works if the devices are bonded?

Comment: You will only receive the IRK when bonding. The exact steps depend on your library, I never used bluenrg before

Comment: I'm currently playing around with the whitelist... will see if that resolves my issue :|

Comment: see update regarding use of whitelist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved by using the `WHITE_LIST_FOR_ONLY_SCAN` property for the `aci_gap_set_discoverable()` function while only bonded devices should be able to connect.